# MVC RedirectToAction Not working Properly

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
```

URL Should be

> http://localhost:6574/Dashboard/Index

But this is showing

> http://localhost:6574/Dashboard/

Showing Error
[image]

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*x}", new { x = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" });
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "UserLogin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: please show your routes config from global.asax

Comment: Is this occurring from IIS?

Comment: Can you also show your Dashboard controller

Comment: Yes this is occurring from IIS

Comment: please can you also show your Dashboard controller

Answer (score 2):

This is likely because your route config contains something like

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Where by your default action is `Index`
Meaning, when you do `RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");` it ignores the index, because this is already the default.

Answer (score 1):

May be this one can helps you, Set this in your applicaiton's `web.config`

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
   <handlers>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
   </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Also you can do this,

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```